# Prove Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem directly

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

We can prove that Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem and Fatou's lemma are equivalent. Almost all the textbooks prove the monotone convergence theorem or Fatou's lemma directly from definition. Can we prove the dominated theorem in such a way?
I want some hints.
Thanks.